# Emgu CV stitching two images together of different sizes

Tags: c#, emgucv, image-stitching

I have two images I want to stitch together.  The images are two different sizes (one is the main image and the other is a small legend).  I'm currently doing:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    long matchTime;
    string modelPath = "C:/Emgu/emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922/Emgu.CV.Example/SURFFeature/model images";
    using (Image<Gray, Byte> observedImage = new Image<Gray, byte>("C:/Emgu/emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922/Emgu.CV.Example/SURFFeature/test images/fridge4.jpg"))
    {
        //returns two different sized images
        Image<Bgr, byte>[] results = DrawMatches.DrawAllMatches(modelPath, observedImage, out matchTime);
        ImageViewer.Show(results[0], String.Format("Matched using {0} in {1} milliseconds", GpuInvoke.HasCuda ? "GPU" : "CPU", matchTime));
        ImageViewer.Show(results[1], "Legend");

        using (Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(true))
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> stictchedResult = stitcher.Stitch(results);//exception here!
            ImageViewer.Show(stictchedResult, String.Format("Matched using {0} in {1} milliseconds", GpuInvoke.HasCuda ? "GPU" : "CPU", matchTime));
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get an `ArgumentException` at the commented line.  When I look at the *View Detail* section, it says `{"Requires more images"}`.  There are already 2 images in the `results` array.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?  Or am I misusing/misunderstanding the `Stitch` class?  There's nothing in [the API](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/75cf18d9-4a41-6225-0242-3a0135e4e078.htm) that I see could be a problem.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Good old Stackoverflow with silent downvoters.  How can a community improve if the community doesn't speak up..

Comment: +1 for providing reproduction code, the exception and its location, as well as the additional information in the details view. Furthermore, it is good that you provided the API reference, it shows that you've attempted to solve the problem on your own prior to asking questions here; we appreciate that. I also couldn't solve your problem by playing around with it, so we've both overlooked something or there's a bug in the library.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray Thanks.  I'm fine with doing any other alternative option with putting both these images side by side.  I just thought this would be the easiest way to do it.  I'm new to emgu-cv and image processing in C#